# Help me to write code of below picture

Tags: draw

how can I write the code of this picture in latex
[image]

Comment: This is very similar to your very recent question. Can't you use those answers? At least to get you started?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! If you haven't done so yet, take a look at the Ti*k*z package.